# Suppress line break in a RichTextBox at certain positions

Tags: c#, .net, richtextbox, rtf, line-breaks

I need to suppress some linebreaks in a RichTextBox.

For example, consider `d6+`. There must not be a line break between `6` and `+`. Basically I'm looking for something like `<nobr>` in HTML.

So far, I've messed around with inserting \u+FEFF etc (which worked on some machines, but some showed vertical lines, maybe a font problem although windows standard font). I also tried to manipulate the rtf directly, i.e. `box.rtf = ...` with putting some `\zwnbo` in there, but I never seem to get it right.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use all of the RichText API with your RichTextBox control.

You may be interested take a look at the following sites:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendmessage - how to send messages to windows using p/invoke.

You can use the `Handle` property of the `RichTextBox` to get the window handle of that control, and then *send messages to it*.

Also look at these include files shiped with SDK from Microsoft, thaty are not going to be used directly in C#, but these files constains all constants you may have to use, such as `WB_ISDELIMITER`, `WB_CLASSIFY` and others.

- *winuser.h*
- *richedit.h*

**In the following example I
   demonstrate how to use the APIs
   provided.**

**EDIT:**

This new sample has code marked as unsafe, but it is better because it does not suffer from the problem of single character string, since I can have a `char*` parameter and manipulate it. The *old sample* follows this one:

*This is C# code*, not C++... to compile it you will have to go to project options and mark the check-box to **allow unsafe code to run**.

*Right click the project -> Properties (Alt+Enter) -> Build -> General -> Allow unsafe code (must be checked)*

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace q6359774
{
    class MyRichTextBox : RichTextBox
    {
        const int EM_SETWORDBREAKPROC = 0x00D0;
        const int EM_GETWORDBREAKPROC = 0x00D1;

        protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnHandleCreated(e);
            this.Text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            NewMethod();
        }

        unsafe private void NewMethod()
        {
            if (!this.DesignMode)
                SendMessage(this.Handle, EM_SETWORDBREAKPROC, IntPtr.Zero, Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(new EditWordBreakProc(MyEditWordBreakProc)));
        }

        [DllImport("User32.DLL")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        unsafe delegate int EditWordBreakProc(char* lpch, int ichCurrent, int cch, int code);

        unsafe int MyEditWordBreakProc(char* lpch, int ichCurrent, int cch, int code)
        {
            const int WB_ISDELIMITER = 2;
            const int WB_CLASSIFY = 3;
            if (code == WB_ISDELIMITER)
            {
                char ch = *lpch;
                return ch == '-' ? 0 : 1;
            }
            else if (code == WB_CLASSIFY)
            {
                char ch = *lpch;
                var vResult = Char.GetUnicodeCategory(ch);
                return (int)vResult;
            }
            else
            {
                var lpch2 = lpch;
                // in this case, we must find the begining of a word:
                for (int it = ichCurrent; it < cch; it++)
                {
                    char ch = *lpch2;
                    if (it + 1 < cch && lpch2[0] == '-' && lpch2[1] != '-')
                        return it;
                    if (lpch2[0] == '\0')
                        return 0;
                    lpch2++;
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**Old Sample Code**

The sample consists of a class that inherits from RichTextBox and places a custom handler using `EM_SETWORDBREAKPROC`. This class will only break lines exactly when over '-' character. Not before, nor after.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace q6359774
{
    class MyRichTextBox : RichTextBox
    {
        const int EM_SETWORDBREAKPROC = 0x00D0;
        const int EM_GETWORDBREAKPROC = 0x00D1;

        protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnHandleCreated(e);
            this.Text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            if (!this.DesignMode)
                SendMessage(this.Handle, EM_SETWORDBREAKPROC, IntPtr.Zero, Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(new EditWordBreakProc(MyEditWordBreakProc)));
        }

        [DllImport("User32.DLL")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        delegate int EditWordBreakProc(string lpch, int ichCurrent, int cch, int code);

        int MyEditWordBreakProc(string lpch, int ichCurrent, int cch, int code)
        {
            const int WB_ISDELIMITER = 2;
            const int WB_CLASSIFY = 3;
            if (code == WB_ISDELIMITER)
            {
                if (lpch.Length == 0 || lpch == null) return 0;
                char ch = lpch[ichCurrent];
                return ch == '-' ? 0 : 1;
            }
            else if (code == WB_CLASSIFY)
            {
                if (lpch.Length == 0 || lpch == null) return 0;
                char ch = lpch[ichCurrent];
                var vResult = Char.GetUnicodeCategory(ch);
                return (int)vResult;
            }
            else
            {
                if (lpch.Length == 0 || lpch == null) return 0;
                for (int it = ichCurrent; it < lpch.Length; it++)
                {
                    char ch = lpch[it];
                    if (ch != '-') return it;
                }
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

It is just a draft, so you may have to further improve it, so you can achieve your goals.

Place the control in a windows form, and run.

Resize the window and see if this is what you want to do!

You will have to make the seeking of word boundaries... I didn't manage to make it work yet.

Comment: I am currently experimenting with it. The method is called at strange times/positions, though. Also, lpch does only contain one character. Maybe it's an encoding thing?

Comment: @Eiko: that happens because the type lpch of `EditWordBreakProc` is a pointer to a character (i.e. `char*` in c++), but the marshaller understands it as being a pointer to a sigle character string wich is not true, it is a pointer to a character in the middle of the text-buffer of the RichTextBox... it is not an encoding problem.

Comment: Maybe I get the variables wrong, but I've set up a text box with "aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbb cccc" in it, and the method gets called with ichCurrent = 15 and cch = 32 (which is longer than the string itself). Break should happen somewhere between b and c here.

Comment: I think I got it working with a couple of modifications. I'll put up my solution as a separate answer later and award you the bounty.

Comment: Just posted the answer. Some modifications were needed, i.e. storing the delegate method to preserve garbage collection, and walking left/right correctly to identify the break positions. It was a good starting point, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but if `RichTextBox` is actually wrapping a Windows rich edit control, you might have some luck by reading this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270412%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Or more specifically this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies to .net at all

Comment: @Eiko It seems the accepted answer assumes what I was suggesting here. But the code will hardly be cross-platform.

Comment: I guess now, about 10 years later, I'd use a different technique altogether. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution (based on @Miguel Angelo, but modified and corrected a bit):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class SpaceBreakingRichTextBox : RichTextBox
    {
        const int EM_SETWORDBREAKPROC = 0x00D0;
        const int EM_GETWORDBREAKPROC = 0x00D1;

        protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnHandleCreated(e);
            AddDelegate();
        }

        [DllImport("User32.DLL")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        unsafe delegate int EditWordBreakProc(char* lpch, int ichCurrent, int cch, int code);
        EditWordBreakProc myDelegate;

        unsafe private void AddDelegate()
        {
            if (!this.DesignMode)
            {
                myDelegate = new EditWordBreakProc(MyEditWordBreakProc);
                SendMessage(this.Handle, EM_SETWORDBREAKPROC, IntPtr.Zero, Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(myDelegate));
            }
        }

        unsafe int MyEditWordBreakProc(char* lpch, int ichCurrent, int cch, int code)
        {
            const int WB_ISDELIMITER = 2;
            const int WB_CLASSIFY = 3;
            const int WB_MOVEWORDLEFT = 4;
            const int WB_MOVEWORDRIGHT = 5;

            const int WB_LEFTBREAK = 6;
            const int WB_RIGHTBREAK = 7;

            const int WB_LEFT = 0;
            const int WB_RIGHT = 1;

            if (code == WB_ISDELIMITER)
            {
                char ch = *lpch;
                return ch == ' ' ? 1 : 0;
            }
            else if (code == WB_CLASSIFY)
            {
                char ch = *lpch;
                var vResult = Char.GetUnicodeCategory(ch);
                return (int)vResult;
            }
            else if (code == WB_LEFTBREAK)
            {
                for (int it = ichCurrent; it >= 0; it--)
                {
                    if (lpch[it] == ' '/* && lpch2[1] != ' '*/)
                    {
                        if (it > 0 && lpch[it - 1] != ' ')
                            return it;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (code == WB_RIGHT)
            {
                for (int it = ichCurrent; ; it++)
                {
                    if (lpch[it] != ' ')
                        return it;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                 // There might be more cases to handle (see constants)
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you need to keep the delegate method around, or it will crash as it gets collected from the garbage collector (which was a pain to debug).

Basically, this subclass only breaks at spaces, which is good enough for my needs at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I've quickly tried this, it seems to work:

```
this.userControl.richTextBox1.LoadFile("C:\\test.rtf");
this.userControl.richTextBox1.Rtf = this.userControl.richTextBox1.Rtf.Replace(@"\par", String.Empty);

this.userControl.richTextBox1.SaveFile("C:\\test2.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

Comment: I don't want to remove all paragraphs. I need to suppress line breaks at *certain* positions.

Comment: Yes it is what I understood but I don't know how you define such data. If you know exactly the text you want to change just do a Find before and then Replace from the Find result on the length of text + \par, no?

Comment: I just set the text of some RichtTextBox. You might even enter it in the box directly. There are no explicit linebreaks.

Comment: What i don't understand is when you say that you want to suppress line breaks at certain positions, what defines "certain"?

Comment: See my example in question. I must not break within "d6+" or "e2-e4". It's as simple as protecting certain regions from breaking. It seems that allowing to break only at spaces will do the job, though.