# Textbox displays line break before plus sign

Tags: c#, string, winforms, textbox, line-breaks

When I have a string like `QgMAAB+LCAAAAAAABAB1UtFuwiAU/RXDsw9QrO36tmi2ly3L4mPTmGulSqTQwGWJMf77wBlXExpe4NxzOedcuBCJot8IdKSa1Rci3bsyO1Bvxn7CEMAOlBNzAs6ZVgKK/` in a textbox, it automatically displays a line break before each plus (+) sign:

[image]

Can I use auto line breaks (WordWrap) and not let the plus sign make it enter a new line?

I want it to look like this:

[image]

(I removed all the plus signs for demonstration)

Comment: Try wrapping your string like: `@"your string"`

Comment: This sadly doesn't solve the issue; it doesn't change anything

Comment: @Jacobus21 you want to get a full width of that TextBox in your designer?

Comment: I want the string to be displayed like this: http://i.imgur.com/4P96dFg.png (I removed all the plus signs for demonstration)

Comment: Have you tried to set : `TextAlignment = "Justify"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually override the word break function of the textbox by subclassing your own textbox.

This worked for me:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace myNamespace
{
    class MyTextBox : TextBox
    {
        const int EM_SETWORDBREAKPROC = 0x00D0;
        const int EM_GETWORDBREAKPROC = 0x00D1;

        delegate int EditWordBreakProc(string lpch, int ichCurrent, int cch, int code);

        protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnHandleCreated(e);
            if (!this.DesignMode)
            {
                SendMessage(this.Handle, EM_SETWORDBREAKPROC, IntPtr.Zero, Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(new EditWordBreakProc(MyEditWordBreakProc)));
            }
        }

        [DllImport("User32.DLL")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        int MyEditWordBreakProc(string lpch, int ichCurrent, int cch, int code)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This is an modification of the excellent EditWordBreakProc example found here:

[Underscore acts as a separator C# RTF Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17871766/underscore-acts-as-a-separator-c-sharp-rtf-box)

Answer (score 1):

This Textbox functionality seems to be by design. Use RichTextBox instead. It does not break on the + sign.

Comment: Weirdly enough, RichTextBox still breaks on about half of the plus signs. http://i.imgur.com/viBkExi.png

Comment: You are correct. The richTextBox has a smarter wrap function but it also treats the + sign in the same way as it treats spaces. It tries to break between whole words if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `WordWrap = false`.

Or you can  use RichTextBox instead of TextBox 
P/S: you can  use RichTextBox instead of TextBox ( But you have to set  `WordWrap = false` for RichTextBox too)

Answer (score 0):

Well actually the text format is weird in our case. If you add:

```
 TextAlignment="Justify"
```

that would solve your problem with `'+'` but you will still have a break line after `\` because he waits a `\n` or `\t` or `\r`.

Comment: So is there any way to make it not break line after any character?

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot format a text in such a way to obtain a full width. As I said you cannot re-format the '\'.

Comment: `"System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" does not contain a definition for "TextAlignment and no extension method "TextAlignment" accepting a first argument of type "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).` I'm using .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a little weird but you can solve the problem of the `\` using

```
String.replace(String, String)
```

or something similar. You can even try to code your own function.
You can check your string and if it occours a " \ ", you'll replace it with " \\ ". I think it should do the trick.

I'm sorry but I don't have enough reputation to add a comment under the fisherXO's answer.

Comment: Yeap, I just referenced that just like an example. But I think it is possible to write a function able to detect "\". For instance, if a portion of string contains /cc, substitute it with //cc or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Namespace
{
    class CustomTextBox : TextBox
    {
        string _text;
        public CustomTextBox()
        {
            this.Multiline = true;
            this.Wordwrap = true;
            this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(CustomTextBox_KeyDown);
            this.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(CustomTextBox_KeyPress);
        }

        void CustomTextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == '+')
                e.Handled = true;
            else
                _text = _text + e.KeyChar.ToString();
        }

        void CustomTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                e.Handled = true;
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Add)
                _text = _text + @"+";
            this.Text = _text;
        }

    }
}
```