# Win32: Edit controls: CTRL+LEFT/RIGHT ARROW should also stop on < or >

Tags: windows, winapi, gdi

With default Win32/GDI edit controls (such as the one in Notepad) hitting the key combinations **CTRL+LEFT ARROW** or **CTRL+RIGHT ARROW** you can skip entire words with the text cursor. But "word" characters don't seem to include characters `<` and `>` (as well as `_`). Let's have this text in such a control (or Notepad):

```
one two <three> four _five_ six
```

Hitting the key combinations always stops after the space character. But I want to define a behaviour where it would also consider the non-letter characters as a word stop, which means: don't stop **only** at `<three>` and `_five_`, but instead **also** stop at `three>` and `five_`.

I seem to have to do this entirely on my own (observing keyboard input). Is there any API access to control this? Has anybody done this before?

Comment: you need by `EM_SETWORDBREAKPROC` set own `EditWordBreakProc` and handle `WB_MOVEWORDLEFT` + `WB_MOVEWORDRIGHT` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761709(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You should tag a language to get more guidance, but here is a C# sample: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17873976/858968

Comment: That's a good direction. Language is irrelevant - everything is a help. Working on a (Delphi) showcase example now...